# How do I simply compare characters in C++?

Tags: c++, char, equals-operator

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char fg;
    cin>>fg;
    char x[20];
    x[0]='0';
    if(fg=x[0])
    {
        cout<<"It's true!"<<endl;
        return true;

    }
    cout<<"It's false!"<<endl;
    return false;
}
```

No matter what input I give, `true` is always returned. Is my syntax off? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah, the number of times I've had this bug. Try == instead of = in the if. As long as x[0] evaluates to true, simple assignment will be true.

Comment: Have you tried to debug?

Comment: @CaptainMurphy, and by evaluate to true you mean evaluate to not 0.

Answer (score 18):

In C++ you use `==` for comparison. The `=` is an assignment. It can be used in the condition of an `if` statement, but it's going to evaluate to `true` unless the character is `'\0'` (not `'0'`, as it is in your case):

```
if(fg == x[0])
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I added a second =, but now it always returns false even if I input 0. Thanks everyone for all of the help so far.

Comment: @DmitriyPotemkin Stack Overflow lets you delete comments if they no longer apply. Point to the comment, and click the little cross next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Within if statement use `==`. For Eg:

```
if (fg == x[0]) {
    //...........   
}
```

`==` compares, but `=` makes `fg` equal to `x[0]`, and that's why you get true every time.